# i want to retrive key value as a String and values value as Double(note :Values value can be store in double after remove % sign)

Tags: java, selenium

This is my base class code ,i want to retrive key value as a String and Values value as Double to compare this in verifier with specific range.(Note:we can Store String values of Values in Double because of removal of % sign)

```
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList al1 = new ArrayList();
    HashMap<ArrayList, ArrayList> hmap = new HashMap<ArrayList, ArrayList>();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'#bottomuppanel')]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(15000);

    List<WebElement> SecuritySliceColHeader = driver.findElements(By.xpath(
            "//td[contains(@class,'dxpgColumnFieldValue_Metropolis dxpgColumnTotalFieldValue_Metropolis dxpgColumnGrandTotalFieldValue_Metropolis lastLevel')]"));
    for (WebElement header : SecuritySliceColHeader) {
        String ColHead = header.getText();
        al.add(ColHead);
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    List<WebElement> grandHeader = driver.findElements(
            By.xpath("//td[contains(@class,'lastVertCell dxpgCell_Metropolis dxpgGrandTotalCell_Metropolis')]"));
    for (WebElement grand : grandHeader) {
        String grandTotalHeader = grand.getText();
        al1.add(grandTotalHeader);
    }

    HashMap<String, String> hmap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
        hmap1.put(al.get(i).toString(), al1.get(i).toString().replaceAll("%", ""));
    }
    for (Map.Entry m : hmap1.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(m.getKey() + "  : " + m.getValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code :

```
        List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("One","two");
        List<String> values = Arrays.asList("1%","2%");
```

// here take your lists (I am just assuming that both of your lists have same size)

```
        Map<String, Double> hMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        String key = keys.get(i);
        String value = values.get(i).isEmpty() ? "0" : values.get(i).replaceAll("%", "");
        Double valueInDouble = Double.valueOf(value);
        hMap.put(key, valueInDouble);

}
```

then printing it you will get your desired output :

```
for (Map.Entry m : hMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + "  : " + m.getValue());
        }
```

You have to take a map of key as String and Value as Double.
Hope that helps you.

Comment: It gives empty String exception As a take all values of List from UI one of Values value is empty so while converting it in double it gives me error so i want to handle this empty value before converting to double @ dangi13 your solution is useful for me but how can i handle this empty value in Values

Comment: I have updated my answer for your condition. here I am setting value as 0 if the value is empty.